# Tailwind installation doesn't apply the CSS in any of my projects

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I installed Tailwind CSS in a mock project because I've had problems with Tailwind before. I follow the installation guide on their website but the CSS doesn't seem to be working. [Here](https://github.com/Ayakk/browserproj) is the link to the repo. I used [this](https://create-project.js.org) to setup the mock project for testing. Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

I have the annotations above in my CSS files.

Comment: did you import your tailwind/css in your root file?

Comment: Did you import TW anywhere? Did you run the build process at least once?

Comment: @MarsAndBack I ran and tested it yes. Do you mean the annotations I need to put in the CSS file with the import? I followed the installation guide word for word.

Comment: @LeviD. Do you mean the annotations? If so yes.

Comment: In your index.html you have `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/output.css">` however that `../` looks suspicious; try without. The path should be relative to the `root`, not to the `src` folder.

Comment: @MarsAndBack When I remove ```../``` it cannot find the output.css file. As the dist folder is in the same directory as the src folder. When the path is ```dist/output.css``` it looks for the file in src/dist/output.css

Comment: I think these are clues

Comment: @MarsAndBack I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: I'm saying your issue probably lies in paths =P. Hopefully someone else can chime in here. On a sidenote, as an exercise, try replicating manually in another environment like [codesandbox.io](codesandbox.io) (or similar). I would eliminate the `create-project-js` from the workflow to narrow it down.